# jquery slider with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I have JSON data that I am displaying I have a cutoff age now I am including a slider once the user changes the cutoff age on slider I want to change the cutoff age based on that. If you look at my code at http://jsfiddle.net/gFzCk/10/  you will see I am displaying 2 colors green and red for records below or above the cutoff age.  When the user moves the slider how can I change the cutoff age based on that.

Comment: The age is changed when sliding [google chrome]. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. give the same `class` for age number on every data.
2. detect the change of the slider cutoff age by `change` event.
3. loop the age elements (use the new class on point 1 as selector) using `each`, and compare the value with `$(this).html()` and `(#number).val()` addClass('green') for one condition and red in other condition

ive update your jfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bondythegreat/MzQEn/1/